# Distance between two values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a array

```
int[] Values = new int[] { 5, 43, 45, 25, 16, 89, 65, 36, 62 };
```

and currently i am calculating the maximum distance between all values `84 = 89 - 5`

```
int MaxDistance = Values.SelectMany((a) => Values.Select((b) => Math.Abs(a - b))).Max();
```

now I want to calculate the minimum distance `2 = 45 - 43`

@ycsun's commment - this doesn't work

```
int MinDistancee = Values.SelectMany((ia, a) => Values.Select((ib, b) => ib == ia ? int.MaxValue : Math.Abs(a - b))).Min();
```

Comment: Try swapping 89 and 5 in your array, and see if Max still works.

Comment: You get zero, because 5 - 5 = 43 - 43 = ... = 0, right?

Comment: Your edit doesn't work because the overload for `SelectMany` that includes the index is the second argument, and not the first, so you'd want `(a, ia)` and `(b,ib)` instead.

Comment: Probably easier to calculate the max distance by `int MaxDistance = Values.Max() - Values.Min();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this instead

```
int MinDistance = Values.SelectMany(
    (a, i) => Values.Skip(i + 1).Select((b) => Math.Abs(a - b))).Min();
```

This makes sure you don't calculate the difference between numbers at the same index or a set of numbers at different indexes twice.  Basically this uses the overload of `SelectMany` that includes the index, then you just want to do your difference with all the numbers after the current index by using `Skip`.

It should be noted that a solution using `for` loops in the form of

```
for(int i = 0; i < Values.Length - 1; i++)
    for(int j = i + 1; j < Values.Length; j++)
```

would be more performant though.

One caveat here though is if you have negative numbers.  Then there will be a difference between the absolute value of `a-b` versus `b-a`.  In that case you'd want to sort the list first to make sure the difference always has `a` as the larger number.

Comment: Could make it a bit faster by sorting first.  Values.OrderBy(x => x).Skip(1).Select((x, i) => (x - Values[i-1])).Min();

Comment: @EyalShulman That won't work because the `Values` you use inside your `Select` lambda is not sorted.  Instead you'd need `var sorted = Value.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();` then `sorted.Skip(1).Select((x,i) => x - sorted[i-1]).Min();`

Answer (score 2):

Just two *simple* loops:

```
  int[] Values = new int[] { 5, 43, 45, 25, 16, 89, 65, 36, 62 };

  int min = -1;

  for (int i = 0; i < Values.Length - 1; ++i)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < Values.Length; ++j) { // please, notice j = i + 1
      int v = Math.Abs(Values[i] - Values[j]);

      if ((min < 0) || (v < min))
        min = v;
    }

  // 2 == 45 - 43
  Console.Write(min);
```